# How to determine a useful center in a 2D range of points

Tags: javascript, tree, quadtree

How do you find the center in a range of points for creating a quad tree node and do so efficiently?

```
class point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
//range = [] of points, (they get sorted into quarters in the tree node)
```

A range represents an array of points, that represent a board.

Here is the relevant code:

```
class quadtreeNode {
    constructor(range, parent, depth) {
        const centerPoint = findCenter(range);
        this.center = centerPoint; 
        this.parent = parent;
        if (range.length <= 1) {
            this.leaf = true;
            this.value = this.center;
        } else {
            this.TL = new quadtreeNode(
                range.filter(x => x.x < this.center.x && x.y < this.center.y), 
                this, 
                depth + 1
            );
            this.TR = new quadtreeNode(
                range.filter(x => x.x > this.center.x && x.y < this.center.y),
                this, 
                depth + 1
            );
            this.BL = new quadtreeNode(
                range.filter(x => x.x < this.center.x && x.y > this.center.y),
                this,
                depth+1
            );
            this.BR = new quadtreeNode(
                range.filter(x => x.x > this.center.x && x.y > this.center.y),
                this,
                depth + 1
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
findCenter(array){
    let centerPoint = null;
    if (array.length <= 1) {
       centerPoint = array[0];
    } else {
        let minX = array.sort((x, y) => x.x < y.x)[0];
        let minY = array.sort((x, y) => x.y < y.y)[0];
        let maxX = array.sort((x, y) => x.x > y.x)[0];
        let maxY = array.sort((x, y) => x.y > y.y)[0];
        const targetX = maxX-minX;
        const targetY = maxY-minY;
        const target = array.find(x => x.x == targetX && x.y == targetY);
        if (!target) {
            return array[(Math.floor(array.length / 2))];
        } else {
            centerPoint = target;
        }
    }
    return centerPoint;  
}
```

I'm a little confused as to how to find the center, whether I need to find the exact center every time, or if there are estimations with a quadtree, or should the range be a specific length divisible by ... 4?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to optimise. Most often you'll want to minimise the depth of the quad tree. So ideally you'd want to choose a node such that the four sub ranges that follow from it, would each have approximately one fourth of the points in range, i.e. an equal distribution. If you would achieve that at each node, then the depth of the tree would be close to log<sub>4</sub>*n*, when *n* is the total number of nodes.

However, it is not always possible to choose such a center node. Imagine this distribution of points in a range:

```
                                         *
                                  *

                                 *

                                *

                             *

                   *
         *
*
```

Whichever point you choose, you'll always produce four subranges of which two are empty, and so the "dream scenario" of an even distribution across 4 subranges is not feasible.

You'll want to choose the center point in such a way that you minimize the size of the quadrant that will get the most points. This may be costly to calculate, but a good heuristic is the following:

- Collect for each point its sort order by x-coordinate (sx), and its sort order by y-coordinate (sy). This you can easily get by performing two sort operations
- Considering that the optimal center would have (sx, sy) = (n/2, n/2), you would select the point for which the distance of (sx, sy) to (n/2, n/2) is minimised.

So the suggested code would be:

```
findCenter(array) {
    const mid = array.length >> 1;
    if (!mid) {
        return array[0];
    }
    return array.sort((p, q) => p.x - q.x) // NB: sort callback should return signed number
                .map((p, sx) => [p, sx]))
                .sort(([p], [q]) => p.y - q.y)
                .map(([p, sx], sy) => [(sx - mid) ** 2 + (sy - mid) ** 2, p])
                .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b)[0][1];
}
```